# Narrator. Scan mode. For TextBlock the narrator reads the Text properties twice

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, narrator

I have a `TextBlock` with dynamic data (Timer). The Text property is updated once per second.

The narrator sometimes (**not always**) reads the text twice in scan mode, because it have two properties with text: `Text` and `AutomationProperty.Name`. I tried to write data directly to the text block `TextBlock.Text = Text;` (not a binding) and to change different parameters `AutomatonProperties`, it didn't help.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

C#:

```
private string _text;
public string Text
{
    get { return _text; }
    set
    {
        _text = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Text");
    }
}
```

How correctly to adjust the `TextBlock` that the Narrator in a Scan Mode read it once?

Answer (score 1):

#### Do you know when narrator is reading your `TextBlock`?

Maybe you can stop text update while narrator is reading text and continue when narrator will stop reading. That can fix the problem.

#### Do you know when narrator starts reading your `TextBlock`?

You can stop text update for a 2 seconds for example. That also can fix the problem.

#### Is `TextBlock` recreation every second do a lot of impact?

You can create a new textblock every second. Maybe that can properly change the behavior of narrator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't know when the narrator is in active state. "You can create a new text block every second." - this great cause, but it's does not work.